# Laravel unisharp/filemanager and unisharp/ckeditor file/image browser/upload shows 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, unisharp-file-manager

what I have done is followed instructions from [filemanager](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation) and [ckeditor](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor)

I have vendor published both filemanager and creditor and vendor publish lfm.php in config

also  `php artisan route:clear
 php artisan config:clear`

Also tried adding `'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth'],` in lfm.php

in view file

```
<textarea name="body" class="form-control ckeditor" id="body-texteditor">{!! old('body',$content->body) !!}</textarea>

<script src="{{ asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var path_absolute = "{{ url('/') }}";
        var options = {
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: path_absolute + '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: path_absolute + '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: path_absolute + '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
            filebrowserUploadUrl: path_absolute + '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token={{csrf_token()}}'
        };

        CKEDITOR.replace('body-texteditor', options);
    })
</script>
```

This is what it outputs

[image: unisharp filemanager ckeditor]

Comment: It was due to guard, to fix this I did `'middleware' => ['web', 'auth:admin']` just added guard to route middleware

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add the guard!
Or try to enable `use_package_routes` in config/lfm.php
or use my version of this package https://github.com/mafftor/laravel-file-manager